# Making a plugin system in clojure

Tags: java, clojure, jvm, lisp

I'd like to know if it's possible to and how to implement a module system.

Here's example of how it works: I have some folder (e.g. `modules`), this folder has a bunch of clojure files that export some variables (e.g. `name` and `regex`), All modules are loaded into one list so it's possible to iterate and modules can be removed from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest thing you could do, is to load all these files one by one with `load-file`. https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/load-file

otherwise you could precompile your plugins' namespaces and load them using some of the java's native techniques (which i don't know much about, but i guess there are some nice libs for that)

**update:**
for some directory named "/my/path" it could look like the following:

```
(run! #(load-file (.getAbsolutePath %))
      (rest (file-seq (java.io.File. "/my/path"))))
```

notice, that the `file` seq traverses the directory recursively, and includes all the files (not only `*.clj`). Maybe you would have to filter them:

```
(run! #(load-file (.getAbsolutePath %))
      (filter
       #(clojure.string/ends-with? (.getName %) ".clj")
       (rest (file-seq (java.io.File. "/my/path")))))
```

Comment: How can I put modules into a list while using `load-file`?

Answer (score 0):

At [riemann](https://github.com/riemann/riemann/blob/0.3.1/src/riemann/plugin.clj), there is a plugin system design which offers the ability to load jar files in the classpath through its initialization scripts. The functionalities allow walking the classpath, looking for small meta files distributed with plugins which hint at the requires.